# Local Area Connection is limited or no connectivity

Tags: networking, windows-xp

win xp sp3

Bottom right I have a message that Local Area Connection is limited or no connectivity.

There is no yellow marks in device manager

When I reconnect modem cable to another comp (also xp sp3) - there is no problem, internet works normally.

Device Manager - Network adapter is Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet.

I tried to change Speed & Duplex option to various values - without success. Current value is `Auto`.

Control Panel - Network Connections - I also tried to disable and enable again the LAN connection - no result.

Any help !

Comment: Do you have one of those LED lights that show status at the connection point (back of computer) to the Network device, what does it do? And on the modem and its lights, what is the status shown on them? Does >IPconfig /all tell us anything useful? Is this static or DHCP? What is the whole routing going on from the internet to the computer? If you think you might have connectivity but issues, did you try pinging by numbers and/or name to check another way?

Comment: @Psycogeek, there is no LED indicating anything. On modem there is no change when I reconnect the cable from and into internet-available comp (the two are in the same room).

I tried `ipconfig/renew` and got the message - `An error occurred while renewing intarface Local Area Connection: unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out`  

Unfortunately I don't know pinging procedure, but definitely I cannot create a connection at all.

Comment: Do you have any software that creates virtual network adapters installed? Like VMware, VirtualBox, Hamachi, VPNs?

Comment: @gronostaj, I think no, I have fresh installed win xp sp3 and just drivers. Maybe something with drivers is wrong, because before OS re-installation there was no problem with internet. But in device manager seems everything ok.

Comment: @Psycogeek, sorry, I see now, there are two small leds on both computers, on the port where modem cable is pluged in. On internet-available comp only the green diode is lightning and on the int.-unavailable comp both, the green and the orange one (maybe this is the red and not the orange) are lighning !

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem this way:

`ipconfig/all` - on the internet-available comp
`ipconfig/all` - on the internet-unavailable comp

Control Panel - Network Connections - Local Area... and manually entered the parameters from the first comp to the another one.